# How can i break a for-loop with an key event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I want to break a for-loop in Python 3.7.3 with a key event. I am trying to make a small game in the turtle graphics.

```
import turtle
from turtle import *

block1 = turtle.Turtle()

def space1():
    block1.hideturtle()

listen()
onkey(space1, "space")

for b in range(1, 200):
    block1.backward(537.5)
    block1.forward(537.5)
```

For now I hide the turtle when I press "space", but I want to break the for-loop with the key event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another callback:

```
...

exit = false
def space1():
    global exit
    exit = True
    block1.hideturtle()

listen()
onkey(space1, "space")


for b in range(1, 200):
    if exit:
        break
    block1.backward(537.5)
    block1.forward(537.5)
```

This is just an example and altough you should not use `global` variables and you should encapsulate all this behaviour, it will be enough.

Comment: The for-loop breaks, but the turtle doesn't hide

Comment: @BrentJanssens, that means you only have a callback available, so mix both of them in a single function. I updated the code, take a look.

Comment: @BrentJanssens, consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and Happy coding!